# CakePHP avoid index/ while passing parameters

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a `programscontroller` and a function `index`

I need to access a list while i enter the url
`mydomain.com/programs`

i need the details of a programe while I enter the url
`mydomain.com/programs/dentalconferance`

ie `dentalconferance` is the parameter for `index`. I need to avoid index from url while passing parameter

Answer (score 2):

In your routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/programs/*', array('controller' => 'programs', 'action' => 'index'));
```

In your ProgramsController:

```
public function index($slug = null){
enter code here...
}
```